# Can there ba a continuous , atom-free random variable $X$ such that $\mathbb P (X \in [a,a+\epsilon])>c>0$ for $\epsilon \to 0$?

Tags: probability

Continuous, atom-free distribution should forbid that from my personal feeling, however, I know that people can construct very extreme random variables such that I am not so sure about the solution anymore...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the distribution of $X$ is atom-free, then for any $a\in \mathbb{R},$ we have, by continuity from above of measures that
$$
0=\mathbb{P}(X=a)=\mathbb{P}(\cap_{n=1}^{\infty} (X\in [a,a+\varepsilon_n]))=\lim_{n\to \infty} \mathbb{P}(X\in [a+\varepsilon_n])
$$ for any sequence $\varepsilon_n$ decreasing to $0$. In particular, you cannot find a sequence of such $\varepsilon_n$ such that $\mathbb{P}(X\in [a+\varepsilon_n])\geq c>0$ for any $n$.

Comment: Sorry that was a bit stupid question; But I could not prove it immediately, so I became a bit insecure; Thank you very much